# problem with inserting multiple string POST in a database table by json_encode()

Tags: php, codeigniter, json

I use jQuery to add a new input. Each row in table contains several inputs, and I want to add the data to the database as an array:

```
<table>
tr 1: <tr>
<input name="name" value="Translate">
<input name="explanation" value="Searches">
<input name="tv" value="Email">
</tr>
<br>
tr 2: <tr>
<input name="name" value="Phone">
<input name="explanation" value="Chat">
<input name="tv" value="Business">
</tr>
tr 3: <tr>
<input name="user" value="jimi">
</tr>
</table>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/y4hb6/)

values for tr 1 is: **Translate** & **Searches** & **Email**
values for tr 2 is: **Phone** & **Chat** & **Business**
values for tr 3 is: **jimi**

I use `json_encode()` on `tr 1` and `tr 2` to encode data and insert it together into the database. `tr 3` is not in that array, it is alone value:

```
$data = array(
    'units' => json_encode(
                 array(
                 'name' => $this -> input -> post('name'),
                 'explanation' => $this -> input -> post('explanation'),
                 'tv' => $this -> input -> post('tv')
                )
    ),
    'user' => $this -> input -> post('user')
);
$this -> db -> insert('hotel_submits', $data);
```

The problem here is that only values "tr 2" inserted into the database.
I want value both(tr 1 and tr 2) together to be insert in the database.

I'm having in database:

```
{"name":Phone,"explanation":Chat,"tv":Business}
```

and I want this

```
{"name":Translate,"explanation":Searches,"tv":Email, "name":Phone,"explanation":Chat,"tv":Business}
```

**UPDATE:**

If there is several `checkbox` in each `tr (1 & 2)` and some of them are `checked`, How are inserted(they) in the database as below:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y4hb6/1/)

```
<table>
 tr 1:
<tr>
    <input name="name" value="Translate">
    <input name="explanation" value="Searches">
    <input name="tv" value="Email">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Mootools" checked> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="PowerTools" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Read">
</tr>


 tr 2:
<tr>
    <input name="name" value="Phone">
    <input name="explanation" value="Chat">
    <input name="tv" value="Business">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Clientcide"> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Library" checked> 
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Framework" checked>
</tr>


 tr 3:
<tr>
    <input name="user" value="jimi">
</tr>
</table>
```

I want in database:

> [{"name":"Translate","explanation":"Searches","tv":"Email", `"checkbox":["Mootools","PowerTools"]`},{"name":"Phone","explanation":"Chat","tv":"Business", `"checkbox":["Library","Framework"}`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since inputs in your rows share their names, the inputs in the last row rewrite values of other inputs. To overcome this, you need to assign names with `[]` and iterate over posted data:

```
 <table>
tr 1: <tr>
<input name="name[]" value="Translate">
<input name="explanation[]" value="Searches">
<input name="tv[]" value="Email">
</tr>
<br>
tr 2: <tr>
<input name="name[]" value="Phone">
<input name="explanation[]" value="Chat">
<input name="tv[]" value="Business">
</tr>
tr 3: <tr>
<input name="user" value="jimi">
</tr>
</table>

$units = array();
$names = $this->input->post('name');
$explanations= $this->input->post('explanation');
$tvs= $this->input->post('tv');
//this works ONLY if you have equal number of names, explanations and tvs
foreach ($names as $idx=>$name){
    $units[] = array(
        'name'=>$name, 
        'explanation'=>$explanations[$idx],
        'tv'=>$tvs[$idx]
    );
}

$data = array('units'=>json_encode($units), 'user'=>$this -> input -> post('user'));
$this -> db -> insert('hotel_submits', $data);
```

This code is not ideal, but it should work, so it's a good starting point. Also, you can't have what you want with `json_encode`, so it will look like

```
[{name:..., explanation:..., tv:...},{name:..., explanation:..., tv:...}]
```

In fact you can, but than you'll have hard time generating and parsing it.

**Update** well, that's tough. The idea is to assign indexes to your inputs explicitly, i.e.

```
tr1:name[0], explanation[0], tv[0], checkbox[0][],checkbox[0][],checkbox[0][]         
tr2:name[1], explanation[1], tv[1], checkbox[1][],checkbox[1][],checkbox[1][]
```

And the loop becomes

```
$checkboxes= $this->input->post('checkboxes');
foreach ($names as $idx=>$name){
    $units[] = array(
        'name'=>$name, 
        'explanation'=>$explanations[$idx],
        'tv'=>$tvs[$idx],
        'checkboxes'=>$checkboxes[$idx]
    );
}
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to say, get them [] in!

Comment: That's a disclaimer for perfectionists hanging around. :) One possible improvement is checking that all arrays really have equal lengths, another - iterating with `for($i=0;$i<$array_length;$i++)` rather than with `foreach`, but those are minor improvements, so it's up to you to implement them. This code should work without any alterations. Have a look on a [guide](http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670) for building ideal code. :)

Comment: That's right. sorry, i have new problem. please see again my update in first post.

Comment: That's right, Please answer to the last question: how get(`select * from <table> ...`) only **name** in this row of database? this output-> `Translate` & `Phone`